# UI heavy loading + animation

Tags: android, listview, animation, user-interface, adapter

So, I am doing an app that should be like this pic:

### [image: infocardapp]

It has one listview, where user selects the content to be displayed, and a content area that will be animated (slide in/ slide out) when content is selected.

The content area must be dinamically built, its layout changes according to the info contained in a JSON request, it is composed of a giant listview wich each item is one info section (see image).

The problem is animating the content area while heavy view loading is done in UI thread causes a huge lag and flicker in animation and view loading cannot be done in threads other than UI thread.

I tried using `AsyncTask` in the adapter for some UI loading to be done in background but only the ViewHolder pattern instantiation and `findviewById` calls could go inside so I didn't get a big perfomance gain. The actual problem is  `.setText()`, `.setImageBitmap()` calls.

Finally the real question is: What can I do to have better performance in this UI loading in order to have a smooth animation?

***Note:*** Consider the data used to populate the content area is being hardcoded for testing purposes.

---

**EDIT:** 
The code used in my content area adapter:

```
public class InfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Info> {

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private final Typeface typeface;

    public InfoAdapter(final Context context, final List<Info> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/"
                + Constants.DEFAULT_FONTNAME);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {

        View infoView = convertView;

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (infoView == null) {
            infoView = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(getItem(position).getLayout(), null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(
                    (TextView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.highlight_title),
                    (TextView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.info_title),
                    (TextView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.info_extra_info01),
                    (TextView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.info_extra_info02),
                    (TextView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.info_description),
                    (ImageView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.info_image),
                    (TextView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.info_subtitle),
                    (TextView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.info_subdescription),
                    (ImageView) infoView.findViewById(R.id.info_subimage));
            infoView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) infoView.getTag();
        }

        final String extraInfo01 = String.valueOf((int) (getItem(position).getValue() / 1));
        final String extraInfo02 = String.valueOf((int) ((getItem(position).getValue() % 1) * 100));

        setDataInView(holder.highlight, getItem(position).getFavorite());

        holder.title.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        holder.title.setTypeface(typeface);

        holder.extraInfo01.setText(extraInfo01);
        holder.extraInfo01.setTypeface(typeface);

        holder.extraInfo02.setText("," + extraInfo02);
        holder.extraInfo02.setTypeface(typeface);

        holder.description.setText(getItem(position).getDescription());
        holder.description.setTypeface(typeface);


        if (holder.image != null) {
            if (getItem(position).getImage() == 0) {
                holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.image.setImageResource(getItem(position).getImage());
            }
        }


        setDataInView(holder.subTitle, getItem(position).getHistoryTitle());
        setDataInView(holder.subDescription, getItem(position).getHistory());

        if (holder.subImage != null) {
            if (getItem(position).getUri() == null) {
                holder.subImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                final Drawable subDrawable = Drawable.createFromPath(getItem(
                        position).getUri());
                holder.subImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.subImage.setImageDrawable(subDrawable);
            }
        }

        return infoView;
    }

    private void setDataInView(final TextView textView, final String data) {
        if (textView != null) {
            if (data.isEmpty()) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView.setTypeface(typeface);
                textView.setText(data);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private final TextView highlight;
        private final TextView title;
        private final TextView extraInfo01;
        private final TextView extraInfo02;
        private final TextView description;
        private final ImageView image;
        private final TextView subTitle;
        private final TextView subDescription;
        private final ImageView subImage;

        public ViewHolder(final TextView highlight, final TextView title,
                final TextView extraInfo01, final TextView extraInfo02,
                final TextView description, final ImageView image,
                final TextView subTitle, final TextView subDescription,
                final ImageView subImage) {
            this.highlight = highlight;
            this.title = title;
            this.extraInfo01 = extraInfo01;
            this.extraInfo02 = extraInfo02;
            this.description = description;
            this.image = image;
            this.subTitle = subTitle;
            this.subDescription = subDescription;
            this.subImage = subImage;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ListView item clicked. Show progressdialog. Download data via AsyncTaks. Fill layout in main thread. Hide progress dialog.  Rollout layout with animation. Reuse views wheneven possible.

Comment: Progress dialog +  data download item click.. I get it, but the laggy part is filling layout in the main thread, if only I could be notified when listview is done loading I maybe could set gone/visible ...

Comment: hmmm... I can't say what is wrong not seeing your code... do not run long time operations in UI thread and everything should run smooth...

Comment: added adapter code in main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line could be a problem:

```
holder.image.setImageResource(getItem(position).getImage());
```

Check what is written about `setImageResource` in the documentation:

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.

For lazy loading of images you should check [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html). You should change declaration `public void download(String url, ImageView imageView)`

to

```
public void download(int id, ImageView imageView)
```

*id* is

```
getItem(position).getImage()
```

Comment: I had to refacot a lot of code and didn't have the chance to test what you said here but it seems that that was probably the problem, activating hardware acceleration while animating also helped a lot.